# Downloaded 2nd Wamp install, uninstalled it, now original WAMP install is not working. Any ideas how to fix it?

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I was running WAMP 3.1 perfectly fine, then accidentally installed WAMP 3.2 instead of updating to 3.2. That ended up breaking my WAMP so it wouldn't work. So, I decided to uninstall 3.2, but now 3.1 is not working. The WAMP icon is just a red square. It says "None of 3 services running".

Answer (score 0):

Here's my notes in case someone else has the same problem. 
I uninstalled 3.2, then installed services in 3.1. Everything went back to working normally. Then updated the normal way though this site: http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/